# Ember.js hybrid application - maybe embeded outlets

Tags: ember.js, outlet

I am creating an Ember.js application which basically has a very simple UI: header, content, footer -- all this in the application layer.

But, when you see the site at first, you have a hybrid application -- google needs to reach parts of it, but login, registration, dashboard, and other pages, should be handled by Ember.

And I might have a bit of an issue, because if I render some views, say on the homepage, in some outlets, then those outlets are going to be different after login, on the user's dashboard.

I cannot show off the UI, but i could try to provide more details if needed.

My question would be how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a bit of a hack for now: just before Ember initialize, I remove from the DOM the content rendered server-side. 
This might be ugly, but it works. This way robots may reach the content I want them to reach, the users on the other hand will see something better.